# xpath combined with local-name and arrays

Tags: xml, select, xpath

I have this and this selects in my xml 'documentNature'

```
//*[local-name()='documentNature']
```

this is returning 2 rows because I have 2 xmls and I would like to return the first one 
kind this (but this do not work):

```
//*[local-name()='documentNature'][0]
```

How should I do this ?
Thanks

Comment: If you can avoid it, do not use `local-name()` to select nodes. Declare a proper namespace prefix and use it `//foo:documentNature`.

Comment: @Tomalak Just for interest, where do you see benefits when doing so?

Comment: The benefit is that the XPath runs faster and is a lot easier to write. Also, you wouldn't forcefully remove namespace checking in other programming languages, it does not make sense to do so in XSLT.

Comment: yeah, valid concerns. also the xml may introduce elements with the same name but a different namespace when it's getting improved once. this would lead to improper results then.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike many other programming languages, in XPath the positions in a node list starting from `1`. Use this:

```
//*[local-name()='documentNature'][1]
```

if you want to select first element having that local-name.

Comment: I tried it I am getting 2 values (I mean //*[local-name()='documentNature'] and //*[local-name()='documentNature'][1] are returning the same value, but I am using xml spy to check and maybe there is something wrong about xml spy

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure XPath indexing starts at 1. Try this:

```
//*[local-name()='documentNature'][1]
```

Aw damn, busted